# Unable to get image src attribute in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I try to get the `src` it returns `None`. The code should locate the image by its class name and get the attribute.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = ('https://www.instagram.com/cats')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

imgs = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "_aagv").get_attribute("src")
print(imgs)

driver.quit()
```

[image]

I tired to use it with for loop as well but the results were same `None`. Any suggestions how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the src attribute using the below locator:

```
time.sleep(3)
images = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._aagv img")

for image in images:
    print(image.get_attribute("src"))
```

Comment: That's the one I was looking into. It worked. Thanks @abisaran

Answer (score 0):

The `div` class has the class that you are searching for (`"_aagv"`). You need to get the inner image element (`<img>`), because it is the element that has the `src` tag on it.

You could either change your selector to match the Image tag directly, or you could select Image tags inside of the `<div>` tag you matched.